How do I fill in the spaces between the column title with a color background?
I made a table with a color on the top row and there are some white spaces in between the columns. Is there any way I could get rid of them and fill them in with my color? This is my output: Output This is my code:
<table style="width:100%;">
  <tr style="background-color:#820000;color:white;font-family:sans-serif;">
    <td style="width:6%">
      Item #
    </td>
    <td style="width:75%">
      Description
    </td>
    <td style="width:8%">
      Quantity
    </td>
    <td style="width:7%">
      Price
    </td>
    <td style="width:4%">
      Cost
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>


To eliminate the white spaces between the columns in your table and ensure that the background color extends across the entire row, you can adjust your table's CSS. Specifically, you want to remove any padding and margin from the table cells. Here’s how you can modify your code:
    <table style="width:100%; border-collapse: collapse;">
  <tr style="background-color:#820000; color:white; font-family:sans-serif;">
    <td style="width:6%; padding: 8px; margin: 0;">
      Item #
    </td>
    <td style="width:75%; padding: 8px; margin: 0;">
      Description
    </td>
    <td style="width:8%; padding: 8px; margin: 0;">
      Quantity
    </td>
    <td style="width:7%; padding: 8px; margin: 0;">
      Price
    </td>
    <td style="width:4%; padding: 8px; margin: 0;">
      Cost
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>


So you say "remove any padding and margin from the table cells." Then you explicitly declare padding: 8px on every table cell.

I note you also added -- but didn't mention -- the border-collapse: collapse which Mr Polywhirl did in his answer, which is kind of key.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

You can achieve this with the border-collapse: collapse rule on the <table>.
<table style="width:100%;border-collapse:collapse">
  <tr style="background-color:#820000;color:white;font-family:sans-serif;">
    <td style="width:6%">
      Item #
    </td>
    <td style="width:75%">
      Description
    </td>
    <td style="width:8%">
      Quantity
    </td>
    <td style="width:7%">
      Price
    </td>
    <td style="width:4%">
      Cost
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

I recommend overhauling this to make it more dynamic:
:root {
  --table-theme-primary-color: #820000;
  --table-theme-secondary-color: #FFF7F7;
  --table-theme-accent-color: #FDD;
}

.awesome-table {
  width: 100%;
  border: var(--table-theme-primary-color) thin solid;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.awesome-table th, .awesome-table td {
  padding: 0.25rem 0.5rem;
}

.awesome-table th {
  color: var(--table-theme-secondary-color);
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.awesome-table td {
  color: var(--table-theme-primary-color);
}

.awesome-table thead tr {
  background-color: var(--table-theme-primary-color);
}

.awesome-table tbody tr {
  background-color: var(--table-theme-secondary-color);
}

.awesome-table tbody tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: var(--table-theme-accent-color);
}

<table class="awesome-table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Item #</th>
      <th style="width:75%">Description</th>
      <th>Quantity</th>
      <th>Price</th>
      <th>Cost</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>00000001</td>
      <td>Item A</td>
      <td>100</td>
      <td>$1.00</td>
      <td>$0.10</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>00000002</td>
      <td>Item B</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>$10.00</td>
      <td>$0.80</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>00000003</td>
      <td>Item C</td>
      <td>10</td>
      <td>$100.00</td>
      <td>$2.00</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>


By default browser stylesheet, table element has border-spacing that gives each <td> space.
To get rid of the space, you can easily add the table element border-spacing:0;
<table style="width:100%;border-spacing:0;">
...
</table>

